# How to convert an object of one class into an object of another class in typescript ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I have two interfaces defined like this:

```
export interface PostView{
    postName: string;
    postTime: Time;
    message: string | null;
    replies: { [P in AccountType]?: Reply[][] };
}

export interface Post{
    postName: string;
    postTime: Time;
    message: string | null;
    replies: { [P in AccountType]?: Reply[] };
}
```

You can see that both the `interface` definitions are same except for the `replies` field.

Now, in a `.tsx` file, I'm getting an object of `PostView`. I want to call another function which requires `Post` object.
Also, for the `replies` field, I have to sent empty object to the function.

This is how I have currently.

```
  const postViewObject: any = props.myPostView;
  postViewObject.replies= {};
  const request: Post = postViewObject;
  functionToBeCalled(request);
```

You can see that I'm assigning `PostView`  object to a variable of type `any` which I don't want to do. And then I'm updating `replies` field to empty object and casting it to `Post` object.

Is there a better way to write this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a new post object using the spread operator:

```
const request: Post = {
    ...props.myPostView,
    replies: {}
}
```